# Why do I get this error? I have written the query according to the tutor

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, inner-join

[screenshot regarding the eroor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZP6I.png)
This is the code if someone wants to tweak it!

```
SELECT
 employee.name AS employee_name,
 departments.name AS department_name,
 eployee.role AS employee_role
FROM
 `bold-bastion-384315.employees_data.employee`
INNER JOIN
 `bold-bastion-384315.employees_data.departments` ON
 employee.department_id = departments.department_id
```

I've got the error in BigQuery. I have got 2 tables 'departments' and 'employee'. I am trying to join the tables with the 'departments_id' being the common column between the two. but time and again it shows that error finding employee. sometime under the 'INNER JOIN' clause and sometimes in the 'SELECT' clause.
Please help!

I tried the query as seen in the screenshot above, and was expecting to get the result but didn't. I am learning this with Google's course on Data Analytics.

Comment: Please (also) use plain text (formatted as code), instead of an image of code. Then we could simply copy it to try ourselves

Comment: Try using the full name of the tables, or define and use an alias

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thank you very much for the "alias" tip! It worked out! Really appreciate your help!